# How can I add inverse distance weighted interpolation layer in openlayer6 using python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, interpolation, openlayers, openlayers-3, geopandas

I have generated a map using ol6(installed using npm & parcel bundle1.12) . and the project is in Python 3.8 & django 3.1. Now I want to show idw interpolation in the map based on point data(the client requires it). How can I achieve it ? I saw idw in python using geopndas and have generated jpg image using matplotlib. Can I add it as a vector overlay in my map?
My map is [image]

I want to generate a map with overlay as below using point data added by the client
[image]

Comment: Maybe this could be of some help https://github.com/fmark/openlayers-pointvis

Comment: but its not working.I can't see the output.